# Realtime Multiplayer Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Which realtime multiplayer plugin is best for unity? I should support realtime networking, and also support push notifications and chatting facility plugin for unity. Also, it can includes facilities for create room and searching room for all user.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about multiple plugins here.

On the topic of multiplayer gaming this plugin is decent and gives you rooms and such out of the box:

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/1786

There many other plugins so keep looking, but this one I have some experience with and liked.

On the topic of push notifications, there are a lot of plugins, but the hard part will be to get one plugin for all platforms (IOS, Android).

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/push%20notifications

I ended up using a combination of my own plugins and https://www.urbanairship.com/, but also look at www.parse.com, or www.kii.com for other solutions.

Comment: Thank you Rudolfwm for your answer i will try this.